# One to One Mapping in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I am new to hibernate and trying to learn some basic concepts.  I have googled a lot about why do we need one to one mapping but I couldnt get a good answer to help a beginner.
Kindly please explain why do we need mapping in hibernate(both one to one and many to one )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with common theory of relational databases?

To answer your question, it would be a good start if you know what entity relationship diagrams are and what they show. The basic point is that you want to display the elements  in your database and their relations in a graphical way.

Let's say your database will contain a table containing cars and one containing people. 
They are totally independent, you can store whatever information you want about both cars and people.
However, when you say each car can be owned by a person, you want to store information which car belongs to which person. The information *car x is owned by person y* is what you call the relation between cars and people.

Now the difference between one-to-one and one-to-many is whether you say each person can own zero or one car (*one person to one car*) or multiple cars (*one person to many cars*).

When it comes to hibernate, you most likely want to apply this theory to objects in your script. Say you have a car object, and that object contains an 'owner' variable (which is an object of your people class). 
Then you tell hibernate to store car and owner separately, because you may need to use the people objects at other points of your script, too.
Mappings will then tell hibernate that the car and owner objects are linked together, even if they are stored in different tables in your database.

I hope this gives you a clearer picture of what you want to do with hibernate and how the mappings fit into it.